# Javascript infovis toolkit (JIT) adding edge event listener in HyperTree

Tags: javascript, graph, infovis, thejit

I'm struggling with adding an edge event listener to the HyperTree object edge in Javascript Infovis toolkit library. I am aware of the fact, that everything revolves around "contains" method, which is not implemented for default edge type, which is "hyperline".

What I did:
I've added code

```
Edge: {
           overridable: true,
           type: 'line',
           lineWidth: 4,
           color: '#bbb'
      }
```

to the HyperTree constructor. 
I've aldo added something like

```
Events: {
            enable: true,
            enableForEdges: true,
            type: 'Native',
            onClick: function (node, eventInfo, e) 
                if (!node) return;
                alert(node);
                if (node.nodeFrom) {
                   alert("target is a node");
                } else {
                   alert("target is an edge");
                }
            }
         }
```

following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547214/infovis-jit-add-click-listener-to-edge). 
I did check in Google Chrome debugger, that `contains` method is triggered on `line` `edgeHelper` objects in jit source library. And when I click on some edge, all `contains` invokations return `true` only for one edge, while returning `false` for the rest of the objects.

Commenting out lines `enableForEdges` and `type: 'Native'` prevents aby triggers on jit `edgeHelper` line `contains` methods.

but if I put a breakpoint on added onClick listener, I get `node == false` whenever I click outside the node (regardless) whether I click on edge or on empty space.

So the question in general: how do I correctly add event listener to edge in HyperTree?

And more narrow question: how can I be sure, that when `contains` for some line return true, it actually triggers a onClick listener, while passing an edge there, rather than a `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in jit.js. I've submitted a [pull-request](https://github.com/philogb/jit/pull/188).